# How to remove the <!--break--> in a RSS feed?

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-6

The teaser divider `<!--break-->` shows up in my full text RSS feed. How can I remove it?

Comment: how is your RSS-feed created? With views? What RSS feed are you serving?

Comment: No, right now I just use the standard built-in way. However I actually tried to create one with views. But as soon as I output the Full Body content it again includes the <!--break--> part. Not sure how I can preprocess content in views before outputting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting RSS feeds can be hard in Drupal. I've used the [contemplate](http://drupal.org/project/contemplate) module to produce  RSS feeds with custom formats. Generally I create the format interactively until I'm satisfied. From there it's simple to export it as a contemplate template file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hestitate to install a new module just for this. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well, you either install a module or you can hack core.